# What can Android Antivirus apps really do?

Tags: android, antivirus

I am studiying about android development and given the permission restriction between apps and isolation that the operating system itself imposes, I was wondering what can an antivirus app distributed as an .apk really do to protect the whole system.

Comment: Snake oil, as they can't do much without root privileges.

Comment: I think antivirus for Android are most useful if you've rooted your phone.